# [MATLAB]: Writing data in Excel return always 1

Tags: excel, matlab, writefile

I want to write an array of increasing integer from Matlab to an Excel file.

So I wrote the following code :

```
T=linspace(1,172800,172800);
xlswrite('example.xlsx',T,'A1:A172800');
```

The result is an excel sheet with the first column (from row1 to row172800) all filled by "1" and not by expected values.

No errors are printed in Matlab workspace.

What I should do to achieve my objective?

Comment: What about `xlswrite('example.xlsx',T);`?

Comment: Not working: Error using xlswrite (line 220)
Excel returned: Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC.

Comment: Ok sou you probably should transpose `T` before passing it to Excel!

Comment: It works! But why? Thank you

Comment: `linspace` apparently make a row and not a column! So you were only writing the first value of it by forcing it to a column range! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to transpose `T` first :

```
T=transpose(linspace(1,172800,172800));
xlswrite('example.xlsx',T);
```

Answer (score 1):

T needs to be transposed,

```
xlswrite('example.xlsx',T','time','A1:A172800');
```